# How to split list element into two?

Tags: python, list, sublist

If I have data stored in a list, e.g.

```
images = ['pdf-one','gif-two','jpg-three']
```

How do I split these into multiple elements at the hyphen - not sublists. I.e.

```
images = ['pdf','-one','gif','-two','jpg','-three']
```

not

```
images = [['pdf','-one'],['gif','-two'],['jpg','-three']]
```

Comment: Including the hyphen?

Comment: yes, it needs to recognise the hyphen, and split the string from there onwards

Comment: What happens if there are multiple hyphens?

Comment: Already checked for earlier in the code using a regex statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case splitting with a regex makes for the most readable code:

```
import re

hyphensplit = re.compile('(-[a-z]+)').split
images = [part for img in images for part in hyphensplit(img) if part]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> hyphensplit = re.compile('(-[a-z]+)').split
>>> images = ['pdf-one','gif-two','jpg-three']
>>> [part for img in images for part in hyphensplit(img) if part]
['pdf', '-one', 'gif', '-two', 'jpg', '-three']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) for this:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> images = ['pdf-one', 'gif-two', 'jpg-three']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[a, b+c] for a, b, c 
                                            in (x.partition('-') for x in images)]))
['pdf', '-one', 'gif', '-two', 'jpg', '-three']
```

Using a generator function for more readable solution:

```
def my_split(seq):
    for item in seq:
        a, b, c = item.partition('-')
        yield a
        yield b+c

>>> list(my_split(images))
['pdf', '-one', 'gif', '-two', 'jpg', '-three']
```